# MYSQL auto increment becomes corrupt

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

For some reason I'm having a issue where after a while my table turns "corrupt" I guess where I get this error:

```
mysql failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine
```

I already found a solution which is to run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

The bad part is that it randomly occurred 3 times so far in 3 weeks without me altering anything in the table. Also the only reason I found out was by hearing it from a user who was unable to register :/

This is the query that is run to register a new user, as you can see it doesn't insert the user_id obviously

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_lastip, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime) 
VALUES(:user_name, :user_lastip ,:user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now())
```

Here is a quick screenshot of my table:

(I had the user_ID length set to 11 before this started to happen and I tried setting it to 255 last time this error occurred but it didn't help)
[image: table image]

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix this? I'm obviously not the only one having this problem so there has to be a logical explanation I hope

Comment: Try this command and see if it fixes the issue, `repair table users  quick`

Comment: You could also post your question on DB Exchange http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks! I guess it worked but the only way I can find out is wait a while and see if it occurs again. Thanks for the help :) I would like to know why this is happening ofcourse

Comment: There could be many reasons one such issue could be the drive is full but hard to say what exactly is. May be try looking the mysql error log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the autoincrement_offset.
Try to drop the table, then create a new table.

Comment: Like I said I already 'fixed' it three times but I need to know what is causing it as it. Completely redoing the table seems kind of useless as it is just going to happen again?

Comment: @Crecket it seems that your increment value greater then a max field length.

Comment: Its set to 255 in length right now and I only have around 3000 users in my table, and the last row used was about 3100 or around there. Unless it randomly added a huge amount that couldn't be it right?

Comment: @Crecket Mysql doesn't add a random huge value. 
You can change int to bigint.